# how to create panel using sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I want to create a panel using sencha.i tried the following code.but it doesn't works.

```
Ext.setup({
    icon: 'icon.png',
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady: function () {
        var main = new Ext.Panel({
            title: 'My first panel', //panel's title
            width: 250, //panel's width
            height: 300, //panel's height
            //the element where the panel is going to be inserted
            html: 'Nothing important just dummy text' //panel's content
        });
        main.render('frame');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a layout for your panel, if you set the "fullscreen" property to true then you should see your panel showing up.

There is a good video tutorial on panel's here http://vimeo.com/15879797.

Hope that helps, I'm just learning Sencha at the moment as well!

```
Ext.setup({
          icon: 'icon.png',
          tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
          phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
          glossOnIcon: false,
          onReady: function() {


          var main = new Ext.Panel({  
                                   title: 'My first panel', //panel's title  
                                   fullscreen: true,
                                   //the element where the panel is going to be inserted 
                                   html: 'Nothing important just dummy text' //panel's content  
                                   });  

          }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble with Sencha Touch the following website is real good: http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-1/.

I've used it myself to learn the basics of developing Sencha Touch applications. The writher explains the code well and shows how to program some basic stuff like localstorage, navigation and lists.